# PostgresException: 42P01 error when trying to retrieve data from postgres in blazor server app

Tags: postgresql, blazor-server-side

I am trying to retrieve data from postgres, am working on a blazor server app.

After creating database called students and a table called studentregistration,i created Classes, service.

Now when trying to retrieve data from a razor component, i get the error
"An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
PostgresException: 42P01: relation "Studentregistration" does not exist"  but because am sure the table name exists, to correct the error, i changed the connection string in appsettings.json.

Now the error message i get is
"An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
PostgresException: 28P01: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.g__ReadMessageLong|194_0(NpgsqlConnector connector, bool async, DataRowLoadingMode
dataRowLoadingMode, bool readingNotifications, bool isReadingPrependedMessage)"

Answer (score 0):

So i was able to solve it by doing the following.

1. The error that password authentication failed, was because i didn't enter
   ; after the password declaration in appsettings.json file.
2. The error "studentregistration does not exist" was due to the the table name in my service.cs and dbcontext.cs starting with an upper case, while in the database the table name starts with a lower case, once i changed the name of the table in the database(from pgAdmin to start with uppercase) the data was displayed in the razor component.